# Insertion into map not happening

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dictionary, vector

We have using map in our visual studio application.In debug mode the insertion is happening fine. But in release mode while inserting in the map, throwing the below exception "Unhandled exception at 0x201a1cfd (dll) in exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdd1." when control passes the below line of code.

```
  "iterator _Where = this->lower_bound(_Keyval);"

mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& _Keyval)
    {   // find element matching _Keyval or insert with default mapped
    iterator _Where = this->lower_bound(_Keyval);
    if (_Where == this->end()
        || this->comp(_Keyval, this->_Key(_Where._Mynode())))
        _Where = this->insert(_Where,
            value_type(_Keyval, mapped_type()));
    return ((*_Where).second);
    }
```

this segment of code is in map file inside external dependencies.

Please anyone suggests the solution..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: u might want to show us your code

Comment: Why does this have both a C# and C++ tag?

Comment: 0xcdcdcdd1 looks like a memory bound, that means you are accessing wrong memory... -> Yes, show your code!

Comment: My_DestPipeLines[CallingCompIden] = (CPipeLine*)CallingCompPL; Here is the line where the exception is happening since the application is big i cant post the whole block of code, here'CallingCompIden' is integer and 'CallingCompPL' is an object handle.

Comment: @chris take it for C++ and i updated it, thank u

Comment: 0xcdcdcdcd is allocated but uninitialized memory.  If I had to guess why the last byte is different I'd say the cast is causing some pointer math.  `CallingCompPL` seems like it is a bogus value at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Probably 
    My_DestPipeLines
is not what you intended. Show us the declaration of it.

Comment: map<int, CPipeLine*> My_DestPipeLines;
this declaration am doing in parent class & using in all child class..

Comment: another possibilit is that the object that "this" points to has been deleted or overwritten.